# Understanding ReactJS Controlled form components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing the following code based on the following page: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

```
class Reservation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isGoing: true,
      numberOfGuests: 2
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      isGoing: this.state.isGoing,
      numberOfGuests: this.state.numberofGuests
    }

    /* Send data in ajax request here */

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Is going:
          <input
            name="isGoing"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Number of guests:
          <input
            name="numberOfGuests"
            type="number"
            value={this.state.numberOfGuests}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Some questions I have about it:

1. Why do we need to store the component values in state? Why not
   just grab the values we need when the form is submitted as normally
   would be done with standard JavaScript? The recommended way would seem to reload the `render` function for every single character typed in or deleted. To me this makes little sense.
2. Since the execution of setState is asynchronous and there may be a delay between `this.setState()` and actually accessing the state with `this.state.numberOfGuests` does this mean that this code may end up grabbing the state before it has been set? If so, why is this code being suggested in the official React docs? If not, why not?

Comment: 1 is fine for very simple forms https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 5):

Regarding point number two, then yes it is logically possible that `handleSubmit` could run before the state update in `handleInputChanged` has completed.  The reason this isn't mentioned in the React docs, or is generally a concern for anyone is because the `setState` function runs **really** quickly.  As an experiment I made [a codepen to determine the average time taken for setState to run](https://codepen.io/alsiola/pen/vxQPwx).  It seems to take in the order of around 0.02 milliseconds.  There is no way someone can change their input, then submit the form in less than that time.  In fact, the `e.preventDefault()` call in `handleSubmit` takes nearly a quarter of that time anyway.

If you have a situation where it is absolutely crucial that `setState` has completed before continuing, then you can use a callback function to `setState`, e.g.

```
this.setState({
    colour: 'red'
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.color)
});
```

Then `red` will **always** be logged, as opposed to the following where the previous value may be logged.

```
this.setState({
    colour: 'red'
});
console.log(this.state.color);
```

Answer (score 3):

Very good questions! Here's my take on them:

**1. Controlled or Uncontrolled - that is the question**

You don't have to use controlled form elements. You can use [uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and grab the values as you suggest in your onFormSubmit handler by doing something like `event.isGoing.value` - plain ole JavaScript (or use refs as some React articles suggest). You can even set a default value with uncontrolled no problem by using, you guessed it, `defaultValue={myDefaultValue}`.

The above being said, one reason to use controlled components would be if you're looking to give real time feedback while the user is still typing. Say you need to do an autocomplete lookup or provide validation like password strength. Having a controlled component that re-renders with the values in the state makes this super simple.

**2. `this.setState()` asynchronous issues?**

[Maybe incorrectly,] I view internally component state updates more like a queue system. No call to `this.setState()` will be lost and shouldn't overwrite another one when dealing with synchronous code. However, there could be a time where a render is running behind a setState update, but it will eventually have and render the most recent value. Ex: the user types 3 characters, but they only see 2, then a short time later they should see the third. So, there was a point in time where the read to `this.state` read an "old" value, but it was still eventually updated. I hope I'm making sense here.

Now, I mention synchronous code above because with asynchronous code (like with AJAX) you could potentially introduce a race condition where `this.setState()` overwrites a newer state value.

Comment: Thanks James. For number 2, I am still a bit unclear. My concern was not about `this.setState()` and `render()`, but more about `this.setState()` and accessing the state in my `handleSubmit()` function. In other words, I am concerned about setState not completing before the values are read in the `handleSubmit` function and sent to my server to be stored in the database.

Comment: In doing a bit more research, it seems that setState attempts to batch updates when called in a single function. As soon as that function returns, it processes the updates. So, if there's a long update function that's taking a long time to complete, and while that function is running someone then clicks submit and handleSubmit fires, there is a chance that it could pull the incorrect data. I think in practice, you have a really, really tiny chance of this happening. Personally, in all my time in React, I haven't seen it happen.

Answer (score 3):

## Why do we need to store the component values in state?

We don't really *need* to store the component values in state and it's perfectly fine to access those values on form submit.

However, storing the component values in state has its own advantages. The main reason behind this is to make React state as the **single source of truth**. When the state is updated (on `handleInputChange` method), React checks the components (or specifically the parts of components or sub-trees) which needs to be re-rendered.

Using this approach, React helps us to achieve what was earlier achieved via [Two Way Binding helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html). In short:

```
Form updated -> handleInputChange -> state updated -> updated state passed to other components accessing it
```

For example say, you have a `<Card />` component which needs input from the user via a `<Form />` component and you wish to display the information as the user types, then the best way would be update your state which would cause React to look for the sub-trees where it was accessed and re-render only those. Thus your `<Card />` component will update itself as you type in the `<Form />`.

Also, React doesn't re-render everything for every single character typed but only those sub-trees which needs to reflect the text change. See the [React diffing algorithm](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) for how it is done. In this case, as you type in the characters in a particular field in the form, only those sub-trees in components will be re-rendered which display that field.

---

## Execution of setState and asynchronous behavior

As mentioned by the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> **State Updates** May Be Asynchronous
>
> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should **not** rely on their values for **calculating the next state**.

Your code should work fine since you're not relying on the previous state to calculate the next state and also you're accessing `this.state` in a different block. So your state updates should be reflected fine; however if you don't want to think about the state updates (or suspect that your code might pick up previous state), React docs also mention an alternative method (which is actually better) that accepts a `function` rather than an `object`:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}));
```

If you're still wondering when you can use the `setState` method safely, use it if other components don't **rely** on the state or when you don't need to **persist** the state (save in local storage or a server). When working with larger projects its always a good idea to make use of state containers to save yourself the hassle, like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).